# Can not remove the expected row from table using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue.I need to remove one particular row from table structure of my app using Angular.js.My code is present inside the below plunkr link.

[code is present here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DAVAcXoWhW2gGYviuFeL?p=preview)

In the above code create 3 row for Monday and fill the required data all should different from each row.Delete the middle row using `-` button,you can check there the last row subcategory is showing wrong.This is my problem.I need if i am deleting any particular row that row data should remove from array and other row will remain constant with the selected data as it was.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/4okaCC?p=preview

Your problem is in your use of $index in ng-repaet. When you delete middle row the $index of the third row change and you reference a wrong catgeory.
I change your plunker to use a function that return subcategories depends on selected category :

```
$scope.getSubCategoryFor = function(answer) {
if(!answer.category) {
  return [];
}

  console.log(answer);
  var result = $filter('filter')(subcategories, {id:answer.category.id});
  console.log('result', result);
  return result;
}
```

and I use this in html :

```
<table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" name="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" ng-model="answer.subcategory" ng-options="sub.name for sub in getSubCategoryFor(answer)">
                <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: yes,it seems its working but i also solved by adding this `$scope.listOfSubCategory[0].splice(index,1);` inside `removeRow` function.its only for 1st day.Any way thanks.